# some php setting?

Tags: php, apache, setting

I'm on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS server, i upgrade my php from 5.2 (forgot version) into latest 5.2.4 from official repo.

After some error with eaccelerator, it run fine, but i have errors in many places in my legacy application (coded by someone else)

Take a look some code, likely he use most PHP4 notation and i would ask if any php setting to compatible with this type of code:

- didn't use " or ' in global variable, example `$_GET[id]`, `$_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD]`
- use `$variable_name` instead `$_POST['variable_name']`
- use `$REQUEST_METHOD=="POST"`

already turning on register_globals but doesn't solve problem

Comment: Install PHP4? Webservers should be able to run multiple versions for different Directories. PHP5.x is not always fully backwards compatible

Comment: for 1, it does not matter (best practice is quote the string). 2 & 3, if not mistaken, it won't work nor a setting to turn that on. it might using the variable variable. do you have something similar to that?

Comment: for installing PHP4 is $_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER will work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such setting in PHP and the PHP 5.2 version tree is not supported anymore. I know this is not the answer you're looking for, but what you should really do is update the application's code to meet the "newly" enforced standards.